# What has been added?

Tags: visual

[image][image]

The two pictures are subtly different, but the real question is: *What is she hiding?*

Comment: 5482 bytes has been added !!

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Can this be a "Find the difference between" puzzle?

Comment: The second image is visually lighter than the first image, but I don't know how that answers the question of what she might be hiding.

Comment: https://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/ by using this, I cannot detech any visual difference, probably there is another file/text etc hidden in one of the photo. (Steganographic)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. But Ivo Beckers answered 1 minute before I did. I think the moral thing to do is to accept his answer.

Comment: I realised this 1 second after I awarded it to you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By using the compare tool [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) this appeared:

> [image]

So she is hiding

> Sausages

Comment: Damn it...I was 1 minute too late. Good find.

Comment: German Mona Lisa.):

Answer (score 7):

Answer:

> She is hiding "Sausages".

Explanation:  Thanks to Oray for reminding me of resemble.js.

> Go to https://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js and upload the 2 picture.
>  Press the buttons on the right:  'Ignore nothing', 'Pink', 'Flat with diff intensity', 'Opaque'.
>  The word "Sausages" appears in the left center part (slightly above the middle).
>
>  [image]

Comment: @GordonK. Thanks for the edit. I guess I saw myself I Monalisa when I said "on the right".